# RedShip sql get Last Saturday query error

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to get Last Saturday date format like `yyyy/mm/dd`

And I'm using

```
FORMAT(DATEADD(wk, -1, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0,getdate()), -1)), 'yyyy/MM/dd')
```

And I have the error:

> function pg-catalog.data_diff("unknown", integer, timestamp without
>   time zone) does not exists. Hint: No function matches the given name
>   and arguments types.

Answer (score 0):

`datediff` takes different arguments. This look like as if it was supposed to be `dateadd`, but it wouldn't make sense.

Try this:

```
format(dateadd(day, -2, date_trunc('week', getdate())), 'yyyy/MM/dd')
```

This will return most recent monday:
`date_trunc('week', some_date_here)` and then you just go back 2 days.